# Promise-based functions for dialogflow's action map

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Setting up a Google Assistant App via the NodeJS Google Actions SDK is done this way:

It seems that these are synchronous functions (per the documentation given on https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/ActionsSdkApp#ActionsSdkApp

```
const app = new App({request: req, response: res});
function pickOption (app) {
   /*A bunch of steps here*/
}
function optionPicked (app) {
   /*Another bunch of steps here*/
}

const actionMap = new Map();
actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.TEXT, pickOption);
actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.OPTION, optionPicked);

app.handleRequest(actionMap);
```

Is it possible for `pickOption` and `optionPicked` to be asynchronous functions? i.e., would it be correct to have `pickOption` be implemented as

```
function pickOption(){
   var pickOptionPromise = Q.defer();
   pickOptionPromise.resolve({
     /*Some results here*/
   });
   return pickOptionPromise.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two functions you'll use most of the time to return a response to the Assistant. `app.ask` and `app.tell`. These wrap your response into a JSON object and return it to Google.

Your `pickOption` and `optionPicked` functions can be run asynchronously and run `app.tell` after your logic is completed.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, there is no requirement that you use `app.handleRequest()` at all. (You don't even need to use `app`, but that's not your question.) It is there as a convenience method to map intents to functions, but you're free to do that task via other means. I tend to do things like

```
function handler1( app ){
  // Does the logic asynchronously, but no voice response for some situation.
  // Returns a Promise that resolves to an Object about what we did
}

function handler2( app ){
  // Does the logic asynchronously, but no voice response for some situation.
  // Returns a Promise that resolves to an Object about what we did
}

function chooseHandler( app ){
  // Some logic which may be async, but which returns
  // a Promise that will resolve to either handler1 or 2
}

function sendResponse( app, handlerResult ){
  // Uses the handlerResult object to determine what to
  // send back to the user. This may involve async database calls.
  // Calls either app.ask(), or app.tell(), or a related call.
  // Returns a Promise indicating success
}

chooseHandler( app )
  .then( handler => handler( app ) )
  .then( result  => sendResponse( app, result ) )
  .catch( err => {
    // Log the error or something
  } );
```

(This is meant to be illustrative. It isn't actually tested, nor guaranteed to be the highest quality or best design for a particular purpose.)

In this, the `chooseHandler()` is usually synchronous, but could be async if we need to do things like check if the user has been with us before and choose a different handler based on that. The handlers are almost always async, and the important bit is that they don't actually pick the phrases that are sent back to the user - that is done in `sendResponse()` and also may involve a database call which is async.